# cyclic functions of order n

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, rotations, cyclic-groups, function-and-relation-composition

Given any $n\in \mathbb{N}$, find an analytic function $f$ with the properties that

(i) $f$ composed with itself $n$ times gives $f^{\circ n}(x) = x$ and

(ii)$f$ satisfies $f(0) = 0$ and $f'(0) = 1.$

For some inspiration, some functions that satisfy $f^{\circ n} = f$ include
$$f(x) = \tan (\tan^{-1}(x) + \frac{\pi}{n})$$
and
$$f(x) = \frac{x\cos\frac{\pi}{n} - \sin\frac{\pi}{n}}{x\sin\frac{\pi}{n} + \cos\frac{\pi}{n}}.$$

I would really appreciate any help on this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $f(z)=z$ is a solution. Now let $f$ any solution. If $f(z)\not =z$, we can write $f(z)=z+az^m+..$ with $a\not =0$ and $m\geq 2$. We compute:
$$f(f(z))=f(z)+af(z)^m+...=z+2az^m+..$$

By an easy induction, we get that for $k\geq 1$, we have
$$f^{ok}(z)=z+kaz^m+...$$

For $k=n$, we get that $ka=0$, a contradiction as $a\not =0$. Hence the only solution is $f(z)=z$.

Comment: Is is possible to find a power series that satisfies (i) and (ii) in any finite field?

Comment: Sorry, I do not know. It is clear that in finite characteristic, this argument does not work.

Comment: Correction: It seem to me that in characteristic $p$, for $f(x)=x/(1+x)$, you have $f^{op}(x)=x$. Verify...