# Cyclic functions of nth order

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functional-equations

I was facing difficulty in calculating an nth order cyclic function for $f:N\rightarrow N$
I tried and found out some of them which are 
$\frac{1}{x}, x, n-x.$ But can't find anymore.
Is there any general form for calculating an nth 
order cyclic function?

Comment: Could you clarify on what you mean by cyclic of order $n$?

Comment: Yes, by cyclic of order n, I mean f∘^n (x)=x ie. f(f(f...n times f(x)))).. For eg cyclic function of two order would be f(f(x))=x. You can also see this [link] (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1879137/cyclic-functions-of-order-n) by @Anonymous.

Comment: $f(x) = \frac{x + \tan \tfrac{2{\pi}}{n}}{1 - (\tan \tfrac{2{\pi}}{n}) x}$

This is one of the many solutions of $f^n(x)=x$ where the function f:R ${\to}$R which comes when we take f as a line

Comment: Sorry, I can't post  answer. Answer ban forbids me to help anyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a paper on the table. We define a function $f$. What this function will do each time is that it will rotate the paper on the table by $\frac{\pi}{3}$. So after applying this function six times, the paper will have rotated by $2{\pi}$, and will be back in the position that it was in originally. Therefore, $f$ is cyclic with an order $6$, since applying the function six times gives you what you originally started out with.

This is incidentally the explanation for cyclic functions. Now if we take a line as a function f:R ${\to}$R, we can apply the same principle as we applied on the paper above, 
We can think of the slope of the line as ${\theta}$, which can be any real number. If a line makes an angle ${\theta}$  with the x-axis, then the slope of the line is given by 
                $m = tan{\theta} $ 
Hence, the operation described above takes a line with slope $\tan \theta$  to a line with slope $\tan (\theta + \tfrac{2\pi}{n})$.
By the addition formula of tangent, 
$\tan \left( \theta + \frac{2{\pi}}{n} \right) = \frac{\tan \theta + \tan \tfrac{2{\pi}}{n}}{1 - \tan \theta \tan \tfrac{2{\pi}}{n}}$

${\therefore}$
$f(x) = \frac{x + \tan \tfrac{2{\pi}}{n}}{1 - (\tan \tfrac{2{\pi}}{n}) x}$

This is one of the many solutions of $f^n(x)=x$ where the function f:R ${\to}$R.

Comment: `f:R→R` But the question (*your* question) was about $f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}\,$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  let $\,A=\{0,1,\cdots,n-1\}\,$ and note that $\,g : A \to A\,$ defined by $\,g(m) = (m+1) \bmod n\,$ is "*cyclic*" in the sense that $\,g^n = \operatorname{id}_A \,$ (where $\,g^n\,$ denotes composition $\,n\,$ times) because $\,n\,$ repeated iterations complete the cycle $\,m\to m+1 \to \cdots \to n-2 \to n-1 \to 0 \to 1 \cdots \to m-1 \to m\,$.

Now consider $\,\displaystyle\mathbb{Z} = \bigcup_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} \{kn, kn+1,\cdots,kn+n-1\}\,$ and define $\,f:\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}\,$ as a $\,g$-like function on each of the subsets of $n$ consecutive numbers:

$$
f(m) \;=\; \left\lfloor \frac{m}{n} \right\rfloor \cdot n \;+\; (m+1) \bmod n
$$

Then, by the same argument as before, $\,f^n = \operatorname{id}_{\,\mathbb{Z}}\,$.